# ZEND Unable to access AutoLoader

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to get my Zend application started on production environment, but i get this error:

> Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: Unable to access /var/www/web1/html/tool/lib/Zend/Loader/AutoLoader.php in /var/www/web1/html/tool/public/index.php on line 24

On development environment everything works just fine, so I figured it has to be a misconfiguration of the server.

Any ideas what could cause the problem?

Comment: Are you executed `php composer.phar update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the development system is Windows and the production environment is *nix.

The correct filename should be:

```
Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php
```

not

```
Zend/Loader/AutoLoader.php
```

Note the `L` vs. `l`.  Windows filesystems are case-insensitive but your production environment is most likely case sensitve which is why it can't open that file.

If that isn't the problem, make sure the permissions on the Autoloader file and parent directories are readable by the web server.